# Using dequeueReusableCell rewrites cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cells

I'm having issues working with tables and cells on Swift.

I've created a simple UITableViewController, with two sections of static cells.

To recap:

- 1 table view
- 2 sections
- 4 cells, 2 in each section
- 2 labels per cell

What I'm trying to do is fill them with data that's coming from a JSON (no problem so far).

All the UI was built with storyboards, not coding.

The problem starts when I try to improve my layout UI. What I want to do is convert those cells to have rounded corners, change their background color, etc. I'm able to achieve that, as you'll see in the code below.

**I'm doing that with this block of code:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5) // white color
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        //Top Left Right Corners
        let maskPathTop = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
        let shapeLayerTop = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayerTop.frame = cell.bounds
        shapeLayerTop.path = maskPathTop.cgPath
        shapeLayerTop.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayerTop.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        //Bottom Left Right Corners
        let maskPathBottom = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
        let shapeLayerBottom = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayerBottom.frame = cell.bounds
        shapeLayerBottom.path = maskPathBottom.cgPath
        shapeLayerBottom.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayerBottom.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        //All Corners
        let maskPathAll = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomRight, .bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
        let shapeLayerAll = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayerAll.frame = cell.bounds
        shapeLayerAll.path = maskPathAll.cgPath
        shapeLayerAll.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayerAll.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)-1) {

            cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerAll
        } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {

            cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerTop
        } else if (indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)-1) {

            cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerBottom
        }

        return cell
    }
```

The problem starts after that code runs, my labels disappear and just the improved layout is preserved, with the colors, cells rounded borders, etc.

What I couldn't find anywhere was a way to preserve those labels no matter the changes over the cells.

Is there a way to achieve that? I'm sure I am missing some theory related to tables here.

I hope someone can help me

**Details:**

- Xcode 8.3.3
- Swift 3.1.1
- iOS 8.4

Comment: Have you tried initializing new `Cell` objects instead of dequeuing?

Comment: you should not override the `cellForRow` method when you are using static cells. try to setup your layout in `willDisplayCell` for example.

Comment: @AndréSlotta thanks a lot! You helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Based on @AndréSlotta reply to my question. This is my final code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5) // white color
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    //Top Left Right Corners
    let maskPathTop = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
    let shapeLayerTop = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayerTop.frame = cell.bounds
    shapeLayerTop.path = maskPathTop.cgPath
    shapeLayerTop.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    shapeLayerTop.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    //Bottom Left Right Corners
    let maskPathBottom = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
    let shapeLayerBottom = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayerBottom.frame = cell.bounds
    shapeLayerBottom.path = maskPathBottom.cgPath
    shapeLayerBottom.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    shapeLayerBottom.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    //All Corners
    let maskPathAll = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomRight, .bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
    let shapeLayerAll = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayerAll.frame = cell.bounds
    shapeLayerAll.path = maskPathAll.cgPath
    shapeLayerAll.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    shapeLayerAll.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)-1) {

        cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerAll
    } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerTop
    } else if (indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)-1) {

        cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerBottom
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone else